# Toolkit to implement Text-to-Speech system for native language

Tags: python, laravel, nlp, text-to-speech, festival

I am creating a TTS system for a native language from which i would create a database of voice recordings from the native people.

I have no experience with Natural Language Processing, and so i would like to know if there are some current tools to achieve my aim?

I am not building from scratch with either laravel or python

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is this python library to programming such systems: https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/text-to-speech/

It is worth taking a look.

You can easily install the library on Linux doing this:

```
sudo pip install pyttsx
```

An example code bellow:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Good morning.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that this library allows you to create your own database of voice.